# CarouselLite is not scrolling continuously

Tags: jquery, carousel, jcarousellite

Iam using `jCarouselLite` to display approx 10 images and I have put `auto` scroll option and Iam scrolling from top to bottom.It is working fine.But I want to scroll continuously without any wait time as like as `marque`.I have tried like

```
$('#my-carousel-2').jCarouselLite({            
        vertical: true,
        btnNext: ".Next",
        btnPrev: ".Prev",
        nextPrevLinks: true,            
        auto: true,            
        responsive:true
    });
```

Can anyone suggest me please.

Comment: have you tried setting time interval 1 sec?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ how can I give..??

Answer (score 1):

[From their Docs](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/?#doc)

see option

> **auto**
>
> As of version 0.4.0, the carousel can auto-scroll as well. This is enabled by specifying a millisecond value to this option. The value you specify is the amount of time between 2 consecutive slides. The default is null, and that disables auto-scrolling. Specify this value and watch your carousel magically scroll.
> speed

Specify milliseconds.

Comment: It still breaks after one slide complete.But i need like a marque.

Comment: look at the scroll  option too